# Right construction of sentence in a wedding reception invitation card

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I would like to print an invitation card for the wedding reception of my son. I am unsure of what to use - a proposition ("to" or "with") or a conjunction ("and") in the following sentence:

"..... reception to celebrate the wedding of Anthony ***to/with/and*** Bethany"

Any advice or inputs on what is more appropriate will be welcome.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry if you're going to edit, please complete the job.

Comment: Surely there must be hundreds of examples online...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I would think an etiquette guide, or wedding planner, or bridal magazine, or even samples in a stationery store would be more authoritative than we are? This is not to send you away, but to point out that one of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate some initial research effort on your own. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: The usual style would be *to celebrate the marriage* - not wedding - *of Anthony (fullname) and Bethany (fullname)* and yes, there must be far more examples than you could ever need not only on-line, but with any printer you care to nominate.

Comment: You nominate printers? Interesting......care to name one?

Answer (score -1):

We invite you to celebrate their marriage. 
The marriage of Anthony and Bethany

Anthony is married to.....
not with

Chris and Debbie got married last summer.
Jamie's getting married to Laura.

source: Cambridge,Oxford
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/married

Comment: Unclear what your answer is.